# MobileFirst - Android push - Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to set up push notification for a native android application using the Mobile First Server. I believe i have everything configured properly according to the documentation but I am receiving the following error...

I am using the Google API version of the AVD emulator (API 21).
I also updated the application-descriptor.xml file on my server to include my sender ID as well as the wlclient.properties file.

```
WLPush.isAbleToSubscribe in WLPush.java:424 :: Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server
```

This is my PushActivity

```
public class PushActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = PushActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private WLClient mWLClient;
private WLPush mPush;
private Button mSubscribe;
private PushListener mPushListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_push);
    mWLClient = WLClient.getInstance();
    mPush = mWLClient.getPush();
    mPushListener = new PushListener();

    mSubscribe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    mSubscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPush.subscribe("myAndroid", new WLPushOptions(), mPushListener);
        }
    });

    mPush.setOnReadyToSubscribeListener(mPushListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mPush != null){
        mPush.setForeground(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mPush != null){
        mPush.setForeground(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPush != null){
        mPush.unregisterReceivers();
    }
}
}
```

My PushListener implementation

```
public class PushListener implements WLOnReadyToSubscribeListener, WLResponseListener, WLEventSourceListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = PushListener.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public void onReceive(String s, String s1) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Notification Received: " + s + ", " + s1);
}

@Override
public void onReadyToSubscribe() {
    WLClient.getInstance().getPush().registerEventSourceCallback("myAndroid","PushAdapter","PushEventSource",this);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,wlResponse.getResponseText());
}

@Override
public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,wlFailResponse.getResponseText());
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission android:name="com.company.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!--<permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"-->
    <!--android:protectionLevel="signature"/>-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".AppState"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.ValidateUserIdActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.ChallengeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_challenge" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".log.LogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_log" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".log.LogDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_log_detail" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.ValidatePasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_password" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".authentication.AccountSelectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_account_selection" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".push.PushActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_push"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.push.PushActivity.NOTIFICATION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.company.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.comandroid.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.company.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Full Logcat

```
GCMClientFactory.getInstance in GCMClientFactory.java:25 :: Using GCMAPIClient
GCMAPIClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMAPIClient.java:132 :: unregister:Receiver not registered: null
WLPush.unregisterReceivers in WLPush.java:820 :: unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@dfee794
WLPush.isAbleToSubscribe in WLPush.java:424 :: Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was re-deploy my native app API from the MobileFirst Server.

Comment: I have the same issue but I cannot solve it... Could you please supply some more info. ? Thanks

Comment: @Stefano Bertini all I did was delete my eclipse workspace and reinstall everything then redeploy. (I'm still doing that at least 4 to 5 times a day) Avoid MFP if you can. Or at least go buy a bottle of Tylenol lol